# what is the meaning of the Object window['0'] and window['1'] in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frame

[image: Sample Image]

I'am a beginners of **javaScript**,and i really want to know what does the **Window['0']** means.
I guess it may be connected with frame element of html,but how and i can not find answer in the book Professional JavaScript for Web Developers 3rd Edition.

Comment: Given that `window === window.frames`, it might make more sense to you if they were called `window.frames[0]`, `window.frames[1]` etc

Answer (score 6):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window
window[0], window[1], etc.
Returns a reference to the window object in the frames. See Window.frames for more details.