# Can't use numbers as property names on window

Tags: javascript, object, properties, window

In Javascript I can't use a string that is just a number as a property name on the window object in Firefox or Chrome, but it works in IE 11. The behavior is the same for any other number I try. If I use a string like "abc" it works as expected.

```
window["0"] = "hello"
"hello"
window["0"]
undefined
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTMaz.png)

However, according to the documentation: "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

I can use "0" as a property name on any other object, but not on the window. Why is this?

This was marked as a duplicate of [what is the meaning of the Object window['0'] and window['1'] in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998963/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-object-window0-and-window1-in-javascript)

and would be, but it seems that the person in the other question wrote his question incorrectly. He asked the same thing I am asking, but meant to ask window[0], not window["0"]. The answer given was for window[0], which is not applicable here.

Comment: do you know what `window["0"]` etc are in the other browsers? Do you know the result of assigning to `window["0"]` in other browsers is?

Comment: Yes, in IE it works as any other object would and properly stores the value. In Firefox and Chrome I get the behavior described in the question.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question, I thought it was the reverse of what you just said

Comment: Sorry, I probably could have worded it better.

Comment: no, re-reading the question I can see it's what you said. In firefox etc, `window[0]` is equivalent to `window.frames[0]` and it is a read property  only as far as I can make out

Comment: Those are [**references to the iframes' `window` objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). You can't just set those (which apparently not a restriction in IE, _how shocking?_).

Comment: is window["0"] the same thing as window[0] ?

Comment: @dlynch Yes, but that has nothing to do with `window`, it's just how bracket notation work. `someObj[ something ]` means that `something` is converted to a string first.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yeah, but 0 is a number literal not a variable so it doesn't get converted at all, it just references the first property on window, whereas "0" is a string and should reference a property on window named "0" which is not necessarily the first property on window.

Comment: @dlynch Open the console and type `undefined[0]` and press enter. Does it say `Can't read property 0 of undefined` or `Can't read property '0' of undefined`?

Comment: You know what, I just tried it and it seems to be coercing the string into a number inadvertently in contradiction with what the documentation says.

Comment: @dlynch Shocking truth: All object keys are **strings**, no matter how you set or access them: `var o = {}; o[true] = 5; o["true"];` => `5`.

Comment: `for(var key in [1, 2, 3]) console.log("key " + key + " is of type " + (typeof k));`

Comment: If that is the case, then why do I get the same results with window["100"]. Surely that property name isn't reserved?

Comment: From MDN link included in your question: _An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string._

Comment: There seem to be some limits of reserved indexes. Note that mine doen't let me assign to `window["100"]`

Comment: It appears that I cannot use numbers as property names on the window object regardless of how large it is. What I want to know is where this is documented?